# Does the character 96 HEX have any special meaning in internet protocols/formats?

Tags: html, email-formats

sorry for the vague subject, the issue is such:

I create an event with invitees in google calendar; on the receiving side an email arrives as multipart, which, in its text/html block, has the following text (quoted-prinatble encoded)

> Wed Jun 9 1pm =96 2p=
>   m

I googled for the =96 and can't find anything. (the charset or this block is windows-1252, BTW)

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character set shows that the value 0096 is sometimes used as a representation of Unicode 2013, an "en dash". For some reason the table on that Wikipedia page doesn't show 0096 in hex, but does show 150 in decimal for that character.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have any special meaning, but it has to be escaped when using quoted-printable.

The quoted-printable encoding uses 7-bit characters as medium, so any character above 7F has to be escaped.