# byte/char allocation in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a type defined in ORACLE. Lets name it as HEADER.

```
create or replace TYPE "HEADER_OT"  as object ("FIELD1" VARCHAR2(25));
```

I am now using this object in a PL/SQL block and assigning a value to this FIELD1 as below.

```
HEADER_OT(some input value of length 24)
```

This **some input value of length 24** has spaces and **-** in it. When i execute my PL/SQL block i get below error

```
Error Occured:ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

If I set it to null it works fine.If i set to value **123456789012345678901234** it works fine again. But if I add two more digits to the above it fails.

I used length and lengthb functions to find the size of my original input, but both give a value of 24.

**Program Manager – Wfd FO** is my original value

Comment: Please re-count the number of characters. You have 29 characters, not 24.

Comment: I used SUBSTR to see what size it accepts. It is working fine till 23 and throwing the same error if i specify 24.

Comment: @FDavidov: To ensure that I used length and lengthb functions in oracle which gave me 24 and not 29. I am assuming that you are talking about **Program Manager – Wfd FO**

Comment: Are you using English characters only? If yes, VARCHAR2(n) allows you to store up to `n` characters exactly (of course, you can store less too).

Comment: Yeah, I did some search on that. I don't find any other characters in the input that i specified. Does **-** take more space than a single character ?

Comment: As long as you use ASCII chars (which include `-`), one char = one space. Try something like `HEADER_TO(SUBSTR('This is a string much longer than you can store in 24 places',1,24));`.

Comment: try `select dump(yourString) from dual` and let's see the result

Comment: What is your purpose? An object type with only one single attribute seems to be quite useless.

Comment: The string `123456789012345678901234` is 24 characters. Are you asking why adding two more characters prevents it being assigned to a 25-character variable?

Comment: Are you using that hypen-minus character you provided in the question (–), or regular hypen-minus (-)? It makes a lot of difference - first one is three byte character, and the other one is only one byte character. You said that you checked lengthb function and it returned 24 - are you absolutely sure you used the original string? For me, lengthb returns 26 characters using string you provided ('Program Manager – Wfd FO'). Edit: use dump, as suggested by Aleksej - for character '–' it will return three bytes.

Comment: I did not copy the string separately. I used select length(column) from table format so that any modifications with the String are taken care of.

Comment: This is the result of dump `Typ=1 Len=24: 80,114,111,103,114,97,109,32,77,97,110,97,103,101,114,32,150,32,87,102,100,32,70,79`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : I specified only one type for simplicity as I know that the problem is with that one particular field in the type.

Comment: Please try `SELECT DUMP('Program Manager – Wfd FO', 1016) FROM dual;` Do you get correct values for `HEADER_OT('Manager – Wfd')`? Or do you get `Manager ¿ Wfd`?

Comment: Does it work with `create or replace TYPE "HEADER_OT"  as object ("FIELD1" VARCHAR2(25 CHAR));`?

Comment: There seem to be two different versions of the string. The one in your question ("**Program Manager – Wfd FO** is my original value") contains n-dash i.e. `unistr('\2013')` which is three characters (hex `e2 80 93` or decimal 226, 128, 147), but your `dump` output shows a decimal 150 (hex 96), while what you actually want is decimal 45 (hex 2d). From [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005515/does-the-character-96-hex-have-any-special-meaning-in-internet-protocols-formats) it seems Windows-1252 uses 150 to represent Unicode 2013 so that could just be what's displayed on screen.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, that is not very precise. En Dash (U+2013) is **one character**. However, when you encode this character in UTF-8 then it uses **three bytes**. Other encoding use only one byte (e.g. Windows 1252), or two bytes (e.g. UTF-16).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit you are quite right, and in a discussion about bytes versus characters I should take care to say what I mean :)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: I should read more about encoding to understand what you have said, but i get the same error on a different OS as well. Some flavor of UNIX i believe. But I am not sure that if you would get different dump value in SQL for the same string stored in database(I am not typing the string to get the dump)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still did not figure out **WHY** is that behavior but i just changed the type to VARCHAR2(50) from VARCHAR2(25) which would solve the problem but still the question of WHY hangs in there.